# minikube not running with virtualbox, how to fix that?

Tags: virtualization, virtualbox, minikube

I am using windows 10 professional edition.
Installed virtualbox and also enable virtualization on bios, that's why able to run windows 10 64bit machines as VMs in virtualbox.

When I started minikube, with below command, getting error as virtualization not enabled.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>minikube start --vm-driver=virtualbox
* minikube v1.19.0 on Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0.19044 Build 19044
* Using the virtualbox driver based on existing profile
* Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
* Creating virtualbox VM (CPUs=2, Memory=6000MB, Disk=20000MB) ...
! StartHost failed, but will try again: creating host: create: precreate: This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory
* Creating virtualbox VM (CPUs=2, Memory=6000MB, Disk=20000MB) ...
* Failed to start virtualbox VM. Running "minikube delete" may fix it: creating host: create: precreate: This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory

X Exiting due to HOST_VIRT_UNAVAILABLE: Failed to start host: creating host: create: precreate: This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory
* Suggestion: Virtualization support is disabled on your computer. If you are running minikube within a VM, try '--driver=docker'. Otherwise, consult your systems BIOS manual for how to enable virtualization.
* Related issues:
  - https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/3900
  - https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/4730
```

How to fix this?

I already enabled in bios as in below screenshot.

[image: bios settings]

Same with --driver also

```
minikube start --driver=virtualbox
* minikube v1.19.0 on Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0.19044 Build 19044
* Using the virtualbox driver based on existing profile
* Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
* Creating virtualbox VM (CPUs=2, Memory=6000MB, Disk=20000MB) ...
! StartHost failed, but will try again: creating host: create: precreate: This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory
* Creating virtualbox VM (CPUs=2, Memory=6000MB, Disk=20000MB) ...
* Failed to start virtualbox VM. Running "minikube delete" may fix it: creating host: create: precreate: This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory

X Exiting due to HOST_VIRT_UNAVAILABLE: Failed to start host: creating host: create: precreate: This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory
* Suggestion: Virtualization support is disabled on your computer. If you are running minikube within a VM, try '--driver=docker'. Otherwise, consult your systems BIOS manual for how to enable virtualization.
* Related issues:
  - https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/3900
  - https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/4730
```

Comment: You can't run both at the same time, since there can only be one hypervisor. The minikube docs say that there is an option to disable that check. It might be needed to make it work. See: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/virtualbox/

Comment: Try with `--no-vtx-check` flag. From [linked github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/3900#issuecomment-474523309)

Comment: I am not running both hypervisors. I am using only virtualbox.

Comment: --no-vtx-check this is starting the process but failing after sometime again with same error

Comment: @user2331760 Try to run `minikube` with [`hyperv`](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/hyperv/) then. As siride said it should be either `hyperv` or virtualbox.

Comment: Hi moonkotte and siride , why hyper-v is coming here in your discussion? No where I mentioned I installed multiple hypervisors. This question is about how to make this virtualbox working, not switching to different hypervisor.  Let me know if you have any on this.

Comment: @user2331760 Because `hyperv` then should be disabled otherwise `minikube` will not start. See [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/application-management/virtualization-apps-not-work-with-hyper-v)

Comment: I don't know where you saw in above output about hyper-v. But hyper-v is never enabled on my machine. Only virtualbox is there.

Comment: @user2331760 Well, I did not see it, but we can't know for sure if it was enabled or not. Last thing to try is to use fresh minikube version. I see that you're trying very old `1.19`. It's very difficult to guess what can be wrong, since usually it just works.